# relative proportions in SQL

Tags: sql

I am puzzled by the results of my query and am trying to understand how it is even possible

I have a table of records of each time a flower was picked:

```
WITH unique_picks AS(

SELECT 
date(pick_timestamp_local) as date
,flower_species
FROM all_picks
WHERE country_id = 1

),

proportions AS(
select 
date
, flower_species
, 100. * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over () as prop
from unique_picks
group by 1,2
ORDER BY 1
)

SELECT 
date
,sum(prop) as total_proportions
FROM proportions
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Each day there were always more than one pick (there were never 0), so the sum of proportions per day per flower species should add up to 1, correct? Given that I am grouping by date, how is it possible that they do not?

However, the resulting dataset looks like this:

```
  date       total_proportions
1 2018-07-16             0.286
2 2018-07-17             0.646
3 2018-07-18             0.591
4 2018-07-19             0.656
5 2018-07-20             0.635
6 2018-07-21             0.699
```

How is this possible given the above query and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with this notation, but it looks like your `prop` field is calculated as the sum of a particular flower picked on a particular day divided by the count of all flowers picked over all time. The only way this could ever be one is if only one type of flower is ever picked, and it is picked on only one day. If I were to completely guess, I would say you want `, 100. * count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (flower_species) as prop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is speculation, but I don't think you are showing the complete data set.

If you ran:

```
select sum(prop)
from proportions
```

Then you should get 100 -- thereabouts.  Because you are multiplying the proportion times 100.

This total sum will be 100, regardless of how many days it is split across.  Your first row is saying that 0.286% of the flowers were picked on 2018-07-16, and so on.  I simply think the result set is missing a bunch of rows that would cause the sum to be 100.